# Trying to get a function formula from workbook

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub tst
    Range(“A1”).Formula = “=Personal.xlsb!convertDate(H1)”
End sub
```

How do I change this formula to call the function when I put the macro in ThisWorkbook instead of my personal workbook?

Comment: Is it in the `ThisWorkbook` module or a regular module?

Comment: It is in ThisWorkbook module

Comment: May I ask why? See for example [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/writingfunctionsinvba.aspx): "The code for a UDF should be placed in a standard code module, not one of the Sheet modules and not in the ThisWorkbook module."

Comment: Okay so would it just be “sheet1!ConvertDate(h1)”?

Comment: `=ConvertDate(H1)`.

Comment: If I put the code in sheet one then it comes up as s 400 error. If I put it in ThisWorkbook then it does not retrieve the ConvertDate function

Comment: Don't put it in the sheet code module, but in a regular module. See my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

Don't put it in the `ThisWorkbook` module or a `Sheet` module, but instead in a *regular* module. Then drop the `Personal.xlsb!`.

```
Sub tst
    Range("A1").Formula = "=convertDate(H1)"
End sub
```